# MS Visual Studio / ASP.NET : show site in multiple browsers when programmer clicks Run?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, cross-browser

Is it possible to somehow make Visual Studio / ASP.NET open multiple browsers when the I clicks Run ? I want to see the page in all browsers I have Internet Explorer, Firefox, Safari, Chrome, Opera  when I click run ????

Sebastian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if there is built-in functionality for that, but you could probably write a program (or script) that takes the site address as a parameter and launches the browsers for you, and then select "Execute external program" as the Run option in the project properties.

Comment: @Kirk Woll: Good point. I'll leave the answer up since he didn't explicitly request debugging, but feel free to suggest better solutions. :-)

Comment: Once the browsers are up, he can then attach to the IIS process and start debugging from there.